# Is there a currently scheduled or announced release date for the Team Drives feature on the G Suite Basic plan?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business, google-shared-drive

[G Suite Team Drives](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/drive/get-started-team-drive/) is currently available for:

- G Suite Enterprise
- G Suite Business
- G Suite for Education editions

My domain is on the cheaper G Suite Basic plan.

You can tell if you are on G Suite Basic by checking https://support.google.com/a/answer/7212025?hl=en. If it says "You need to upgrade" at the top then you are using G Suite Basic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because any answer would be speculation.  Google is the only one that can answer this definitively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of announces are made on https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/

It's worth to note that the Team Drive announcement made on March 2017, was updated to announce the inclusion of G Suite for Nonprofits, but there is no mention of the G Suite (basic).

https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/03/introducing-new-enterprise-ready-tools-google-drive.html